# Flutter - How to select an item (tag) automatically in the UI - List<dynamic>

Tags: flutter, dart, listview, dynamic

I am trying to preselect a particular tag shown on the right of the image.
However, I am unable to figure out where to set it. The tags are coming from an API (Postgres backend).

Once it is built to a list of overlay as shown on the right again in the screenshot. I just wanted it to preselect, "Morning", "Evening" or "Daytime" based on the time of the day.

To start off with, I am not able to preselect anything in "selectedTags". This can only be done manually by the user when clicked on a tag.

The method is shared below.

```
showTagPicker(context, allTags) async {
    await showModalBottomSheet(
      isDismissible: false,
      enableDrag: false,
      backgroundColor: Colors.transparent,
      isScrollControlled: true,
      context: context,
      builder: (builder) => Center(
        child: Container(
          width: double.infinity,
          decoration: BoxDecoration(
            borderRadius: BorderRadius.all(
              Radius.circular(10),
            ),
            color: Colors.white,
          ),
          margin: EdgeInsets.all(16),
          padding: EdgeInsets.all(24),
          child: ListView(
            shrinkWrap: true,
            children: <Widget>[
              Text(
                "Please pick your tags",
                style: TextStyle(fontSize: 16),
              ),
              Padding(
                padding: const EdgeInsets.symmetric(vertical: 8.0),
                child: TagPicker(
                  height: MediaQuery.of(context).size.height * .6,
                  tags: allTags,
                  onTagSelected: (_selectedTags) {
                    selectedTags = _selectedTags;
                    print("----->");
                    print(selectedTags);
                    print("<-----");
                  },
                ),
              ),
              Row(
                mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.end,
                children: <Widget>[
                  RaisedButton(
                    color: PRIMARY,
                    textColor: WHITE,
                    onPressed: () {
                      Navigator.of(context).pop();
                      navigateToAnalysis(context);
                    },
                    child: Text("Save"),
                  ),
                ],
              )
            ],
          ),
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
```

I tried, adding "print" to debug and see what and where things are being set but I did not get any further, I have also shown the debug screen if it helps.

Any direction here to preselect one/many tags would be helpful.

Please let me know if I must provide additional details to solve this.

Also, I know there are several things in the code which might be wrong, it is inherited code and I am struggling a bit.

Edit: Including TagPicker. It is not a public library but our widget.

```
class TagPicker extends StatefulWidget {
  const TagPicker(
      {Key key, this.height, this.tags, this.onTagSelected, this.selectedTags})
      : super(key: key);

  @override
  TagPickerState createState() => TagPickerState();
  final double height;
  final List tags;
  final List selectedTags;
  final Function onTagSelected;
}

class TagPickerState extends State<TagPicker> {
  List selectedTags = [];

  @override
  void initState() {
    super.initState();
    if (widget.selectedTags != null) {
      setState(() {
        selectedTags = widget.selectedTags;
      });
    }
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return widget.tags != null
        ? Container(
            constraints: widget.height != null
                ? BoxConstraints(maxHeight: widget.height, minHeight: 60)
                : BoxConstraints(),
            child: SingleChildScrollView(
              child: Wrap(
                spacing: 0.0,
                children: List.generate(
                  widget.tags.length,
                  (index) {
                    return Padding(
                      padding: const EdgeInsets.only(right: 4.0),
                      child: ChoiceChip(
                        selectedColor: PRIMARY,
                        labelStyle: TextStyle(
                            fontSize: 12,
                            color: selectedTags.contains(widget.tags[index])
                                ? WHITE
                                : Colors.black),
                        label: Text(widget.tags[index]['tag_name']),
                        selected: selectedTags.contains(widget.tags[index]),
                        onSelected: (selected) {
                          setState(() {
                            selectedTags.contains(widget.tags[index])
                                ? selectedTags.remove(widget.tags[index])
                                : selectedTags.add(widget.tags[index]);
                            widget.onTagSelected(selectedTags);
                          });
                        },
                      ),
                    );
                  },
                ),
              ),
            ),
          )
        : Container();
  }
}
```

[image]

Comment: Can you share the TagPicker widget?

Comment: Which plugin are you using for the tags? I couldn't find a flutter `TagPicker` with a quick search.

Comment: Included TagPIcker

Answer (score 0):

Pass `selectedTags` as an argument to `TagPicker` and modify `TagPicker` to render an initial set of selected tags. As before `onTagSelected` callback will provide an updated set.